# Don't know why error with indices occurs in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Consider the following matlab code fragment:

```
g = @(x, t)x.*0;
u_explizit = explizit_Euler(20, 800, 1, 1, zeros(21,1), g, [1;2], 0, 0.1);
figure
surf(u_explizit);
shading flat;
title('Aufgabe 2 - Explizit Euler');

u_implizit = implizit_Euler(20, 800, 1, 1, zeros(21,1), g, [1;2], 0, 0.1);
```

Both functions `explizit_Euler` and `implizit_Euler` start with the same commands (here shown for `explizit_Euler`:

```
function [u] = explizit_Euler(n, nt, T, kappa, u0, f, b, gN, gD)

tau = T/nt;

[A, z] = prepare_system(n, f, b, gN, gD);
z = z';
...
end
```

The function `prepare_system` looks like this:

```
function [ A, z] = prepare_system(n, f, b, gN, gD)
%PREPARE_MATRIX_SYSTEM Prepares A_h and solution vector f_h

    h = 1/n;
    z = f((0:n)./n);
...
end
```

The call of `prepare_system` from within `explizit_Euler` works just fine. However, the call from within `implizit_Euler` delivers an error message and I just can't figure out why:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
Error in implizit_Euler (line 5)
    z = f((0:n)./n);
```

It seems that matlab thinks `f` is a vector, and thus it can't access `f(0)`, which makes sense if `f` was a vector. But `f` is a function handle! And how come the exact same code works fine in an earlier code from within `explizit_Euler`?

Comment: Are yo sure you dont use before f as a vector?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes, I've just checked my scripts. Plus, I renamed it and it still wouldn't work

Comment: I've found out, that the function handle is turned into a vector when `implizit_Euler` is called. I just can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missplaced the parameters in the signature of `implizit_Euler` (!) - sorry, guys!